# 3D Carousel on Timer

Tags: javascript, 3d, carousel

I have created a 3D rotating carousel that is currently controlled by a "Next" and "Previous" button. I want to remove the buttons and have the carousel rotate automatically by a timer, like every 5 seconds it transitions to the next image.

I have been trying different things but I keep breaking the code. I'll paste the original unbroken code below. Thanks for your help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class=" js csstransforms3d"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- disable zooming -->
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="carousel.css" media="screen">

<script src="carousel.js"></script>
<script>

    var init = function() {
        var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel'),
            navButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#navigation button'),
            panelCount = carousel.children.length,
            transformProp = Modernizr.prefixed('transform'),
            theta = 0,

            onNavButtonClick = function( event ){
                var increment = parseInt( event.target.getAttribute('data-increment') );
                theta += ( 360 / panelCount ) * increment * -1;
                carousel.style[ transformProp ] = 'translateZ( -115px ) rotateX(' + theta + 'deg)';
            };

        for (var i=0; i < 2; i++) {
            navButtons[i].addEventListener( 'click', onNavButtonClick, false);
        }

    };

    window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', init, false);  
</script>

<body class=" ready">

    <section class="container">
        <div id="carousel" style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(-115px) rotateX(0deg);">

            <figure style="opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(115px);">
                <img src="image1.png">
            </figure>

            <figure style="opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: rotateX(120deg) translateZ(115px);">
                <img src="image2.png">
            </figure>

            <figure style="opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: rotateX(240deg) translateZ(115px);">
                <img src="image3.png">
            </figure>

        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="options">

        <p id="navigation">
            <button id="previous" data-increment="-1">Previous</button>
            <button id="next" data-increment="1">Next</button>
        </p>

    </section>

<footer>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's `setInterval()` to repeatedly call your carousel animating function after a set amount of time, instead of having the button clicks trigger the animating function.

Note that with the button clicks, a value is being passed to that function that determines the direction of the carousel spin. This is being passed via an event object, `event.target.getAttribute('data-increment')` and won't be available once we disable the button click events. I'm assuming this value isn't really needed anymore as you're probably going to have the carousel advance in one direction only so you can remove that entire line and change the next line to a fixed forward advance:

```
theta += ( 360 / panelCount ) * -1;
```

Here's the entire script block rewritten with the button code removed and a `setInterval()` line added. `onNavButtonClick` renamed to `carouselAdvance`:

```
<script>
var init = function() {
    var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel'),
        navButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#navigation button'),
        panelCount = carousel.children.length,
        transformProp = Modernizr.prefixed('transform'),
        theta = 0,
        carouselDelay = 5000,

        carouselAdvance = function( event ){
            theta += ( 360 / panelCount ) * -1;
            carousel.style[ transformProp ] = 'translateZ( -115px ) rotateX(' + theta + 'deg)';
        },
        carouselInterval = setInterval(carouselAdvance, carouselDelay);
};

window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```